# Updating DB row with another row (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table Emp and I want the address id of row 2 to be the same as the address id of row 1, can I do it without a stored procedure?

Something like

```
UPDATE Emp SET address_id = (SELECT address_id FROM Emp WHERE id = 1) WHERE id = 2;
```

Maybe I can do something like update Emp e1, Emp e2 set ... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you mate.

```
UPDATE Emp t, (SELECT address_id
    FROM Emp
    WHERE ID = 1) t1
SET t.address_id = t1.address_id
WHERE ID = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your update can work(on other databases), but to MySQL's insistence that a table can't update itself, i.e. you can't do this:

```
update tbl
  set address = (select address from tbl where name = 'paul')
where name = 'george';
```

But you can do a work-around: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f373/6

```
update tbl
  set address = ( select address from 
                      (select address from tbl where name = 'paul') x )
where name = 'george';
```

Anyway, you should go with [Gregology's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524668). That is future-proof, you can use it when you want to update two or more fields. Gregology's answer demo in sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f373/10

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

UPDATE Emp 
SET address_id = (SELECT t.address_id FROM Emp t WHERE t.id = 1) 
WHERE id = 2

-- aliasing of tables can only be done thru the subquery of an update statement.

Rhian A. (NZT)

Answer (score -1):

In fact, the query you posted should work. This feature is called subqueries.

Comment: In MySQL you can't update a table by querying from the same table in a subquery :(

Comment: I see - sorry, didn't know that.